# Where can I edit/see the HTML of this Wordpress free theme?

Tags: html, wordpress-theming

the answer to this one will probably be obvious to many of you, but I recently decided to make a website for my girlfriend and expand my knowledge while doing that. So here is my dilemma:

I am using the Blossom Mommy Blog theme, which is a child of the Blossom Feminine theme.

Below a single post page, there is a previous post/ next post navigation menu and the "previous/next" text is in English and I want to change that to be in Bulgarian. I was able to see this in the browser debugger, but I can't seem to find where this comes from in the theme files themself, so any help would be really appreciated!

P.S. I even prepared a screenshot, but apparently I cannot attach files here...

P.P.S. Tried looking at the parent and child functions.php, also the templates, but could not find this HTML. Looks like some function is calling it, but I have no idea where to find this function.

With many thanks,
Dobri

Answer (score 0):

Function: previous_posts_link();
Function: next_posts_link();

Use: 
previous_posts_link( "Your label" );

More info:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_posts_link
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_posts_link